# Insert a view into a block or a node using a shortcode

Tags: 7, views

I need the following:

I have a view that lists my portfolio projects the projects have a term reference field for its category. I want a shortcode for insert the view into some of my nodes and be able for apply arguments or filters for example:

- Category 1 AND Category 2
- Category 1 OR Category 2
- Or simply listing the project node IDs: 333,332,334

I found the [Insert view module](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view) with that module I can make a shortcode like this

[view:view_name==arg1/arg2/arg3]

but how I told you I need to be able for filter in the short code Category_1 AND Category_2 for example or list the given node IDs

How would you do this using [Insert view module](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view)?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be one of passing in context.

A better option is to install either the Display Suite Module, or Page Manger with Panels. It is great for passing context and creating custom views outputs on your node .With both of these options you have far more control, and if you invest in learning the ins and outs of at least one of them you will not be sorry.

I will walk you through using Display Suite:

Install CTools' Views content panes. Create a base view that lists whatever you need listed, then add a Content Pane (from CTools) to the view. Add a relationship to the term in question, and then any and all contextual filters that would be needed. Lastly, under PANE SETTINGS in views, click on Argument input, select From context for each of the contextual filters, and slect the required context for each of them.

Install Display Suite. In the display of your node type, select a layout (one column should be fine) to activate display suite to render that view mode. Create a new dynamic field. Drag it to wherever you want it displayed. Click on the gear next to it, and at the top would be a Edit content link. Click that, and select View panes, then the view you just created. It will then ask for you to select the context for each of your views contextual filters. Node being viewed is what you select.

Now when you view the node it pulls in that view with the required contextual filters and displays its output as a field.

Comment: Thanks for your effort in the answer, but this is not what I need, I need to have a shortcode in order to insert it into any node body or block... I found an answer I will post it later

Comment: @SsouLlesS When?

Comment: Ho man I forgot and now I don't remember I don't use Drupal anymore anyways 